# Sentiment analysis of entity using stanford nlp

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I extracted all the entities present in a particular sentence. For example if my sentence is

```
  infrastructure is good, Work-culture is pathetic,hikes are not good either
```

I have developed a code that gives me entity. now i need sentiment based upon entities. my output should be something like

```
infrastructure--> positive
work-culture--> negative
hikes--> negative
```

how am i supposed to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are done with the coding next thing which is the most challenging part is to train the system with proper content. I have worked in Google prediction API for same sentiment analysis. You need content for the matter, means if it is a movie review then the training content should contains lots of movie review. I can tell you I have trained a system for movie review analysis with 30 movie review contents(15 positive and 15 negative). Still the system does not give 80% perfect result.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Stanford NLP package then it comes with a sentiment analyzer.
See http://nlp.stanford.edu/sentiment/